# JavaScript Error "Object does not support this property or method" in IE6

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-6, popup

There is no error while loading the page but if i click on the page after successful loading, the js error pop up comes up with "Object does not support this property or method" message. No errors encountered in IE7 or FF3, it is happening only with IE6

What could be the reason for this? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: -1. You need to post the javascript code on the page, or it will be impossible to debug.

Answer (score 2):

You have Javascript code either in the page or included from it which doesn't consider the differences between the various browsers, and is trying to access a property or method of some object that IE6's Document Object Model does not have.

If you can link/post to the source of the page and the scripts in it it would help us a lot in finding the code that causes this.

Comment: This error won't just be thrown for DOM-related issues - it will also be thrown if you try accessing a non-existent property of ANY object...

Comment: @Max : thanks dude. The source code is very use, thats why i didnt paste here. As it is an index page, it has lots of js and php files included which makes it difficult to trace the faulty method/function exactly.

@J-P : thanks, i shall check that too.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you download and install something like [Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/). When you get the error you can simply select "debug" and the debugger will pop up on the line that is causing the problem.

Comment: Given the limited information in the question this is the best answer +1

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.

i have linux in my machine. How can i install MVWD in a linux machine?

Comment: The same way you install IE6. And yes, I run linux too ;)